# Log in using Google without logging into Google

Tags: google-account, oauth

I log into Stack Overflow (and others) using Google. I don't have any alternative means of login in many cases, like an email/password combination - Google is the only way of accessing those accounts.

Now the scenario is that I am on an untrusted computer and want to access eg. Stack Overflow. However, I don't want to log in to Google as I would put my primary email at risk.

How can I log in to SO/some other service anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Stack Overflow recognizes you only because Google tells it who you are; and for that, Google has to recognize you first.

---

Alternatives:

- Enable two-factor authentication for your Google account. Even if your password is stolen by a keylogger, it won't grant others access to your account.
- Use a different account for authentication with less important sites that you will want to use casually at an airport / internet cafe. This may be too late if you already registered, but at least Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general) allows you [to add more credentials](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials) to your account.

Comment: I am open to semi-hacks, like migrating a cookie.

Comment: I surely hope that SO security measures prevent any such hacks. Having someone with your stolen cookie getting access to your account would be highly undesirable.